# How to copy multiple lines and paste multiple times under each line separately?

Tags: vim, putty

original below. I want to copy each line and paste multiple n times under their own lines separately.

```
USD
XYZ
ABC
YUT
LMO
.
.
. upto so on
```

want them to become like this. Any way how can I achieve following in Vim?

```
USD
USD
USD
USD
USD
USD
XYZ
XYZ
XYZ
XYZ
XYZ
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC
YUT
YUT
YUT
YUT
YUT
LMO
LMO
LMO
LMO
LMO
.
.
. upto so on
```

Comment: Please look it now. I have edited it

Comment: Sorry for the wrong interpretation. I dont know how to properly ask a question actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to a find/replace on your entire file

```
%s/.*/&\r&/gc
```

Breakdown

```
%s    start a substitute on the entire file
.*    capture the entire line to be replaced
&\r&  replace with the entire captured group. Add \r& as amount of required duplicates
```

Comment: Lieven I have 226 unique rows of currency codes and I want every line to be pasted 226 times under their each lines, so the total will be 51529 rows. Can you please be more specific on the command according to my problem. I am facing some ambiguity to execute according to my requirement

Comment: In that case, you could do `:let @q=Y225p225j` followed by `226@q`

Comment: its giving me two errors undefined variable and invalid expression

Comment: Sorry, missed the quotes: `:let @q="Y225p225j"`

Comment: The macro could be more concise: `:let @q="Y225gp"` because we can place the cursor after the paste using `gp`.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering with awk

```
 :%!awk '{while(++i<257)print;i=0}'
```

Reference: [www.unix.com](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/213795-duplicate-line-n-times.html)